# Angular - Would a form in a ng-view be assigned to parent controller by default

Tags: angularjs

I have an index.html in which I'm using `ng-controller="Main as main"`.

In this index.html I have a `ng-view` and also then a routes in which:

```
when("/", {
      templateUrl: "views/home.html",
      controller: 'Home',
      controllerAs: 'home'
})
```

Now in this home.html - i'm defining:

```
<form name="myFirstForm">
   //form contents
</form>
```

However whenever I do `$scope.myFirstForm` I keep getting `undefined`.

I want to ask would this form not take `main` as the controller i.e. from the parent?
If not how can i enforce it?

If i try wrapping that in `<div ng-controller="Main as main">` then can i am right to assume it makes another instance of that controller?
And if this is the case,  can i still force it to the parent controller from index.html? If not how do i access it?

A lot of questions/hope its clear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MyFirstForm is just a name of your DOM form element. It has no connection with the scope. If you want to access the forms data then add ngModel to the input elements in the form. Then you'll be able to access them from the controller without specifiying the controller in the view